# Read committed, no locks. Screwed up

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server-2008, transactions, transactionscope

I have a weird problem from production systems. I have readCommitted transaction defined with read operation with no_lock and write operation with table lock in the same scope.

However, multiple processes are able to override the lock and able to perform write operation with great impact. Please help!. Thanks.

```
using (TransactionScope transaction = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TransactionOptions() { IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted }))
{
    dataAccess.ExecNonQuery("GetNextOrder", parametersList); //read orders from table 1, there is NO_lock in the SP

    orderIDParameter = (IParameter)parametersList[0];
    int orderIDParameterValue = (int) orderIDParameter.Value;

    if (orderIDParameterValue != NullOrderID)
    {
       parametersList.Clear();
       IParameter orderIDLockParameter = SQLClientFactory.GetParameter("@OrderID", orderIDParameterValue, Direction.In);
       IParameter lockNameParameter = SQLClientFactory.GetParameter("@LockName", lockName, Direction.In);
       parametersList.Add(orderIDLockParameter);
       parametersList.Add(lockNameParameter);

       dataAccess.ExecNonQuery("Insert_SP", parametersList);  //Insert into table 2

       orderID = orderIDParameterValue;
    }

    transaction.Complete();
}
```

Stored procedure: `GetNextOrder`

```
SELECT top 1 @OrderID=ht.OrderID        
     FROM dbo.table1 ht WITH(nolock)       
     left join dbo.table2 htl WITH(nolock) on ht.orderid = htl.orderid        
     WHERE ht.Status in (0,1)
```

Stored procedure: `Insert_SP`

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[Insert_SP] (
@OrderID INT,
@LockName VARCHAR(50)
   )
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON

 insert into table2 (OrderID, LockName) VALUES (@OrderID, @LockName) 

SET NOCOUNT OFF
END
```

Comment: So how does the other SP look? Under which circumstances do you have a problem?

Comment: I have updated the SP. One possibility is that multiple processes calling the same code. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: How have you determined that "multiple processes are able to override the lock and able to perform write operation with great impact"? And btw, you are not using a table lock in your insert SB but a row lock.

Comment: Still in the process of finding whether multiple processes is the problem. Primary key constraint is defined for table 2. I believe in SQL lock defined is equivalent to rowlock and table lock.

Comment: On primary key constraint, we have thread.sleep defined.   if (e.InnerException.ToString().Contains("PK_Table2_OrderID"))
                        {
                            _pcsLogger.AddLogEntry(Logger.Severity.Warning,
                                                   "OperationsProcessor->Attempting to re-try next transaction.");
                            Thread.Sleep(_pollingInterval);
                        }

Answer (score 0):

How is your dataAccess class defined?

I suspect it's not enlisting in the new transaction - use

```
connection.EnlistTransaction(Transaction.Current)
```

in that class.

Comment: Each process has only one thread. How does enlisting the transaction help?

Comment: @Adarsh Well, without that, the transaction scope won't apply to your code.